# Prove/Disprove if $\sup \left\{\sqrt[n]{a_n}:n\ \in \mathbb{N}\right\}<1$ than $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_n \ge 0$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Prove or disprove: if $\sup \left\{\sqrt[n]{a_n}:n\ \in \mathbb{N}\right\}<1$, than $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty$.

I think that this one is false.

We know that if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}<1$ than the series converges, but if the limit doesn't exists than it can diverge or converge.

So I want to take a split series, between even and odd, such that $\sup \left\{\sqrt[n]{a_n}:n\ \in \mathbb{N}\right\}<1$, but the limit of $a_n \ne 0$, or something like that, so the series converges.

Am I on the right way?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: if $q<1$ is the supremum then $0 \le \sqrt[n]{{a_n }} \le q \Rightarrow 0 \le a_n  \le q^n$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: @Gary Oh nice!! So it it less than a geometric series with $|q|<1$, so by comparison test it converges $\to$ the statement is correct. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: There is a $c<1$; $c$ nonnegative; and an integer $n_0$ such that $\sqrt[n]{a_n} \le c$ for all $n \ge n_0$. [Indeed any $c$ strictly between the $\lim \sup$ and 1 suffices.]
Then $\sqrt[n]{a_n} \le c$ implies $a_n \le c^n$. So the inequality $a_n \le c^n$ holds for each $n \ge n_0$ and so
$$\sum_{n \ge n_0} a_n \le \sum_{n \ge n_0} c^n \le \frac{c^{n_0}}{1-c}, $$ the last inequality following because $0\le c <1$.

Can you fill in the rest.

Comment: Thank you! So by comparison test - the statement is true, am I correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Thank you Mike!

Answer (score 0):

Denote $\overline{s}=\sup\left\{ \sqrt[n]{a_{n}}:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ and let $q=\frac{\overline{s}+1}{2}$. $\;\forall  n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have:
$$\sqrt[n]{a_{n}}\le\overline{s}<q<1\Longrightarrow$$
$$0\le a_{n}<q^{n}<1$$
Hence $\;\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}}$ converges by the direct comparison test.

Comment: Thank you! We can also denote $q$ to be the sup as Gary suggested.

Comment: You are right. haven't seen his comment, only his answer which looked different to me on first sight.  I wouldn't post it otherwise. Anyways I'm glad it worked out for you!